# Save multiple values of a command line option in Perl array

Tags: arrays, perl, command-line

I have a script that needs to take some options, one of these is -i (input).
I tried the following code to get the input parameters into an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my @input = ();
my $help = '';
my $other = '';

GetOptions(
    'help'          =>  \$help,
    'input=s{1,}'   =>  \@input,
    'other=s'       =>  \$other
);
```

When I try to run it as `./my_script.pl -i param1 param2 -o aaa` I get this:

```
Error in option spec: "input=s{1,}"
```

If i run it explicitly with perl as `perl my_script.pl -i param1 param2 -o aaa` everything works smoothly.
Is there a way to get these parameters into an array (not using `@ARGV`) without explicitly invoking perl from the command line?

Comment: Which version of Perl is this?

Comment: What does `which perl` return?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I do have different Perls, and it works on both of them. Executing `./script.pl` will invoke the Perl named in the shebang, which is `/usr/bin/perl`. That's your system Perl. Calling `perl` might, as @Zaid implied, give you a different Perl that you have installed as well, possibly with Perlbrew.

Comment: Add `warn Getopt::Long::VERSION` after the `use Getopt::Long` and tell us what each of them says. Are they different? Mine are (because of what I said above).

Comment: Multiple perl versions it is. One is `5.8.5` and the other is `5.8.8`. Thank you all!

Comment: I don't think the problem is the Perl version, but rather the version of Getopt::Long that came with it. One might be so old it doesn't support that syntax.

Comment: When I switched to invoking perl v5.8.8, the script ran with no errors. I guess it's the version of the Getopt::Long module  as you suggested.

Comment: You should add that as an answer yourself so future readers can find it, and accept the answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I have more than one version of perl installed. One of them (the older one) probably has an older version of the Getopt::Long module that doesn't support the `input=s{1,}` syntax. When I switched to invoking perl from the most up-to-date version installed, the script ran with no errors.